# Shutdown thread disappears when performing endpoints call

Tags: java, multithreading, sigkill, sigterm

I have a Java application running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When the application receives a shutdown signal, a shutdown sequence is run like this:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            shutdown();
        }
    });
```

This works fine, but as soon as I try to call an external REST endpoint (I am using Retrofit with Rx Observables) the thread disappears exactly there, the endpoint is never called, and consecutive commands are not executed anymore.

- I first thought Observables would be the problem and used the Retrofit `Call` instead. Same problem.
- I then tried to make a synchronous call, instead of calling the endpoint async. Same problem.
- The time for the shutdown is not the problem. I explicitly gave 30 secs.

I assume this has to do with threading, e.g. when a library creates extra threads while shutting down, the JVM seems to kill everything.

Can anybody shed light or suggest what else I could try, please.

--

Extra information:

I need to perform long-running cleanup. Problem is I cannot determine how the shutdown signal looks like and when it happens, because the JVM runs in a Docker container which, upon `docker stop` (when the host is stopped), first sends `SIGTERM`, then, after a timeout (which I can set, currently 60 secs) `SIGKILL`. The JVM in the container runs socket.io where potentially thousands of clients can be connected. I want to use the 60 secs to send a `good-bye` to each client and cleanly disconnect these, as well as unregister the server from the loadbalancer. So there are a lot of potentially blocking operations during cleanup.

If Java believes that cleanup is always short, then Java is wrong :(

Comment: Shutdown hooks should exit as quickly as possible, and certainly not engage in network operations. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When shutting down the JVM in your case raises the interrupted flag. So as soon as you call any blocking operation, that one will immediately be terminated by an InterruptedException.

If you must execute further, potentially long-lasting code at the termination of your application, then the shutdown hook is not the way to go. That one exists to close open resources, not to create new ones.

As you gave no further information about your code I cannot give an exact advise, but the general idea is to have the main thread wait while the application is running, and have that one do the cleanup work. In this case you however need a shutdown signal that is not a system shutdown signal, so the application can continue to run normally.

If that is for some reason too complicated, you can try to clear the interrupted flag at the beginning of your shutdown hook by doing something like:

```
try {
  Thread.sleep(1);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

This is however against the rules, and those exist for a reason. i.E. the OS might consider your program to be hanging if it does not react on a kill signal fast enough and terminate it in worse ways.

Comment: This answers my question. I still added extra information above in case you have more ideas. But I guess interrupting the thread is the only thing I can do, and it's rather safe as the "OS is Docker" which will send `SIGKILL` should my interrupted thread not exit on time.